# Using SQL Server rowversion instead to datetime to track changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, rowversion

To fetch any record from table that are either inserted or updated, I am using created on date to get inserted records and updated on date to get rows in which any column is updated.

Simple select query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE ([Table].CreatedOnDate >= @Date OR [Table].UpdatedOnDate >= @Date)
```

(`@Date` is just a parameter passed to the stored procedure)

Now this table has grown to over 30 million rows and this query is timing out.

I have read about `rowversion` at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) and [here](http://aspalliance.com/1785_Understanding_TIMESTAMP_ROWVERSION_in_SQL_Server.5)

Can I use SQL Server's `[Rowversion]` column instead of these two date columns to prevent time outs? Is `Rowversion` faster for searching then date search?

Comment: You're the one with the tables and data. You're the one who can, reasonably easily, set up a comparison and determine the answers to your questions.

Comment: To support Damien_The_Unbeliever: Read [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Silly question: Is there an index on the two date columns you are targeting? Did you check the actual execution plan?

Comment: `ROWVERSION` does **NOT** store date and time - it's a **binary counter** - so this is **NOT** something you can easily use to do date range searching ....

Comment: Also, if possible, do *not* use `SELECT *` - but select **only** those columns you really need. If you do this, you might be able to create a **covering index** that contains all the columns you need, to speed up selection quite a bit !

Comment: I would create a (persisted) computed column that stores the "relevant" date for a change (so either createdondate or updatedondate) and create an index on that column. Thus the condition can be simplified to `where relevant_change_date >= @Date` which very often can be better optimized than an `OR` condition